# OCP Java SE 6 Practice Questions - WeatherTest Enum

Tags: java, enums, static, open-closed-principle

A question in "OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practice Exams (Exam 310-065)" Assesment test 2.

Given:

```
public class WeatherTest {
static Weather w;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(w.RAINY.count + " " + w.Sunny.count + " ");
}

enum Weather {
    RAINY, Sunny;
    int count = 0;

    Weather() {
        System.out.print("c ");
        count++;
    }
}
}
```

> What is the result?
>
> A. c 1 c 1
>
> B. c 1 c 2
>
> C. c c 1 1
>
> D. c c 1 2
>
> E. c c 2 2
>
> F. Compilation fails.
>
> G. An exception is thrown at runtime.

The answer the book says C.

But when I try running this code I get compilation error, saying "The static field WeatherTest.Weather.RAINY should be accessed in a static way".

Which is correct and expected, but no one has complained about it on internet, so I am wondering if I am missing something? Has it got something to do with Java version or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code compiles and gives answer C.

All that is happening is that your IDE is issuing you with a warning that you should not access static members on an instance of a class, as it it confusing. `w.RAINY` makes it look like `RAINY` is an instance field, when in fact it is static. In this case `w` is actually `null`. The usual way to access static members is to use `ClassName.member`. Here you should write `Weather.RAINY`.

Comment: I agree with this, but did not expected even a warning from a book of this stature but good to know whats going on behind the scenes. thanks

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin I think the book is probably really good, but this code is deliberately awful. It's designed to look like `w.RAINY` might throw a `NullPointerException` or the code might not compile or `count` might get incremented twice. You should not write code like that!

Answer (score 2):

The book is right and the correct answer is C, `c c 1 1` as can be tested [here](https://ideone.com/dC3DS6).

This error is produced by your IDE which was promoted from a warning. Assuming that you copy-pasted all the code correctly. Don't use IDE when preparing for that exam, use simplest text editor and `javac`.

It has nothing to do with Java version, it works the same in all versions of Java SE 6 and higher.

Last but not least - never write code like that. This is only exam hokus-pokus...

Comment: So i have tested this on JDK 1.6.18 and JDK 1.7.0.21 and it fails to compile, very odd...

Comment: @SyedSirajUddin Under Windows? Copy that text into file `WeatherTest.java`, compile with `javac WeatherTest.java` and run with `java WeatherTest`, what's the output? Are you using an IDE? Maybe it's because of it. I tested on my machine with 1.7.0_75 and `c c 1 1` is printed.

Comment: yes @Adam you are right, I was using the IDE, I tried using the normal notepad thing and tried compiling with javac and running it with java, it works fine.

I think it was the eclipse IDE which I was using was throwing a warning and I assumed that to be a compilation error. cool now I know the difference :)

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using? Eclipse comes with internal java compiler. Be aware when you use eclipse old version.